# How do I make this map with animated pins?

Tags: javascript, css, dictionary

Here's the website:
http://www.hungvuongpanga.com/en

Please scroll down to the Market section. You will see the pins raining down, and when you hover the pin, it will jump up. How do you create these effects?

Comment: did you already try something?

Comment: I think it was made with javascript, which I'm not familiar with. I just wonder if there is any premade plugin that I can use to create the same effect.

Comment: wich effect are you looking for? "animated pins"? take a look in [codrops](http://tympanus.net/codrops)

Comment: Thank you! What about the "raining pins" effect when you scroll to the Market section? Is it made with Javascript?

Comment: its made with Jquery or javascript yea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bassed on the comments, Yes you are looking for some Javascript/Jquery effects.

Check out the [WOW.js library](http://mynameismatthieu.com/WOW/).

Here is the [Live DEMO](http://www.materialup.com)

Just wrap yours content inside a HTML `<div>`

```
<div class="wow">
  Content to Reveal Here
</div>
```

And init with JS like this.

```
<script src="js/wow.min.js"></script> 
<script>
 new WOW().init();
</script>
```